# Problem with ferrite bead - reduces power supply voltage

Tags: voltage, ferrite-bead, lan8720

I built my own board with a [LAN8720](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/00002165b.pdf) chip but I can't get it to work. I found out that the [ferrite bead](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1912111437_Murata-Electronics-BLM18KG471SN1D_C413961.pdf) I used only outputs ~1.4V from 3.3V input, which is way too low.

I used some guidelines and other boards as examples for the layout. The first one used this [bead,](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/445/742792662-1720736.pdf) the other is uses this one [MPZ1608B471.](https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/517083/TDK/MPZ1608B471A.html)

Because my electronics dealer didn't have either of those, I tried to compare the data and took the one I linked first.

Did I make a mistake there? I don't really undestand the data from ferrite beads.

The datasheet doesn't help much either as I can only find "bead" in this picture:

[image]

Here is the schematic from my board. Ignore Q4 as it was removed and bridged. L1 is the bead.

[image]

Overall, my ESP gets the clock signal but can't initialise the PHY (LAN8720) chip and my RJ45 doesn't get enough power, either. (The diodes don't go on.)

Comment: My suggestion would be remove the bead, replace it with a 0 ohm resistor and check the voltage again. I suspect something else is happening and the ferrite is not the issue.

Comment: Have you got all the recommended decoupling capacitors on the 3.3 V regulator?

Comment: "Ignore Q4 as it was removed and bridged..."  quadruple check that the 'bridging' operation didn't bridge more than you hoped for.  Try: Removing power.  Remove the bead.  Check resistance from each side of the bead footprint to gnd (looking for an unintended path to GND).

Comment: Will try with bead removal. What is the purpose of the bead here in the first place I thought its just for decoupling the voltage. The 3V3 voltage come frome a ESP32 inbuild ams1117. I think they are good decoupled as they use the same voltage for the chip.

Comment: The bead provides an RF impedance to allow the capacitors on either side of it to do their shunting work additively. A properly operating ferrite bead will have near DC zero voltage across it, more than a few 10s of mV probably means it's broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved.
As some people told me, the bead was the problem. I changed it. Now th circuit works like a charm.